# With a long line of code what is the standard for breaking down

Tags: java, formatting

Java code example:

```
public String toString() {

   return (title + '\n' + border + '\n' + getEmpID() + " " 
           + getLastName() + " " + getFirstName() + " " 
           + getHours() + " " + getRate() + " " + getGross() + border);}
```

As you can see it's a long toString override.

Where is the standard place to break the line of code down into smaller bits. Before the `'+'` after the `'" "'`? Help please! :)

Also, if you could show me how to properly place the {} that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to your local conventions, basically. I would personally:

- Remove the `(` and `)` around the whole expression; they make no difference
- Use string literals everywhere instead of character literals; that avoids accidentally ending up performing integer addition instead of concatenation
- Break lines *before* the `+` operator, which makes it clear that the start of the next line really *is* in the middle of an existing statement rather than being a new statement. (This is a general convention, not limited to this situation.)
- Be consistent in whether you break before a space or before a value; you're already doing this. (I don't think it matters much which way you're consistent, or even whether you're consistent between different statements - but within a single method it's nice to be consistent.)
- Move the closing brace to the next line
- Add an `@Override` annotation

That would end up with:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return title + "\n" + border + "\n" + getEmpID() + " " 
        + getLastName() + " " + getFirstName() + " " 
        + getHours() + " " + getRate() + " " + getGross() + border;
}
```

You might also consider using [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead of string concatenation - and possibly also *consider* having just one value (and space) per line, leading to code which is longer but easier to change, e.g.

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return title + "\n" 
        + border + "\n" 
        + getEmpID() + " " 
        + getLastName() + " " 
        + getFirstName() + " " 
        + getHours() + " " 
        + getRate() + " " 
        + getGross() 
        + border;
}
```

It's worth noting that your `toString()` method *always* uses `\n` as a line break regardless of platform. That's a reasonable decision, but one you need to be aware of. Personally I usually don't include line breaks in `toString` results, but that's your call.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String toString(){
   return (title + '\n' + border + '\n' + getEmpID() + " " 
           + getLastName() + " " + getFirstName() + " " 
           + getHours() + " " + getRate() + " " + getGross() + border);
}
```

We usually do the following braces placement. And for example for if-statement

```
if (condition) {
 // do smth
} else {
 // do smth
}
```

Comment: I see! So no blank space between method declaration and return value, and the break in the line of code should be before the + operation. Just making sure I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see - you were only talking about brace placement. Sorry, misunderstood, and downvote withdrawn.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to break before each significant keyword:

```
return (title + '\n'
      + border + '\n'
      + getEmpID() + " " 
      + getLastName() + " " 
      + getFirstName() + " " 
      + getHours() + " " 
      + getRate() + " " 
      + getGross() 
      + border);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this way.

```
public String toString()   
{   
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
   sb.append(title).append('\n')      
   .append(border).append('\n')      
   .append(getEmpID()).append(" ")     
   .append(getLastName()).append(" ")    
   .append(getFirstName()).append(" ")    
   .append(getHours()).append(" ")    
   .append(getRate()).append(" ")     
   .append(getGross()).append(" ")
   .append(border);

   return sb.toString();    
}
```

Comment: What do you believe the benefit of a StringBuilder is here? It looks more distracting than the string concatenation form to me. Also, if I *were* using this I would indent the `.append` lines.

Comment: I would rather use `MessageFormat.format` or `String.format` which gives a more readable code. I'd leave string builders for string building within loops.

Comment: String concatenation is more expensive operation. That's why I prefer StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to **follow the convention being followed by your team**. Always remember that they will be the ones reading and maintaining this code so following the standard set by your organization would be best.

For concatenation, I would recommend using `String.format()` which gives a `printf` style of string formatting and parameter substitution. `MessageFormat.format()` is something I prefer however as it uses `{0}`..`{n}` which I honestly find more readable. Both returns the formatted string.

`String.format("%s %s %d", "foo", "bar", 3)`  would give string "foo bar 3"
`MessageFormat.format("{0} {1} {2}", "foo", "bar", 3)`  would ALSO give string "foo bar 3"

For braces, this would be the one prescribed by the

```
if(condition) {
    // code block
    // code block
} else {
    // code block
    // code block
}
```

According to Oracle Java Coding Conventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

- Open brace “{” appears at the end of the same line as the declaration statement
- Closing brace “}” starts a line by itself indented to match its corresponding opening
  statement, except when it is a null statement the “}” should appear immediately after the
  “{“

Note however that many developers are irked by this behavior called ***"cuddling an else."***

You could also use **Checkstyle** which is an eclipse plugin to auto-format these things for you as you save your work.

Again, I would reiterate to follow the standards of your team above all else.

Answer (score 0):

I would better use

```
StringBuilder
```

It provides better performance. String - concatenation creates a new String after each concat, because a String is immutable.

StringBuilder instead is a mutable String representation.

It´s bad practice to do such a String-Concatenation like you do in your example.

Regards

Comment: _"String - concatenation creates a new String after each concat"_ - while this is allowed by the language spec, no Java compiler I've used is this inefficient. Instead, the entire expression will be evaluated by allocating a single `StringBuilder` and appending each of the terms of the expression, creating exactly one new `String` object. (This behavior is also allowed by the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).) Compile OP's code and look at the generated bytecodes to see for yourself.